# ember-simple-auth multiple authenticator architecture

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I am trying to implement multiple login options in my ember-cli site (so you can authenticate via facebook, google, or my own oauth2 server). However, I'm a little at a loss as to the right way to accomplish this. As far as my research goes, I can see that there are multiple ways to do this using [`ember-simple-auth`](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth).

The first option is to simply use [`ember-simple-auth-oauth2`](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-oauth2), and create authenticators that extend that for each login method. This is a combination of the [Authenticated Account](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/4-authenticated-account.html) and [Multiple External Providers](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/7-multiple-external-providers.html) examples provided by `ember-simple-auth`. Obviously, this would mean writing all my authenticators myself including the ones for facebook/google.

The second option I see is to use [`ember-simple-auth-torii`](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-torii) to authenticate each of my login methods, as in the [Torii](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/12-torii.html) example provided by `ember-simple-auth`. However, I simply cannot find a good oauth2 example to help me create a provider for my custom oauth2 server. If anyone could help me out with this by showing me how to add a custom oauth2 provider to `ember-simple-auth-torii`, I would appreciate it.

Finally, the last option (that I can see) is a combination of the two above - Using `ember-simple-auth-torii` authenticators for google/facebook, and a `ember-simple-auth-oauth2` authenticator for my own server. Obviously, I don't really want to rely on 2 separate ember-simple-auth packages, but if I have to I can (I'm assuming doing this would work?).

If anyone could pipe in on these methods or suggest a new one to allow me to do oauth2 authentication via facebook, google, and a custom server, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: could you describe how did you finally combine with both packages? I am getting the authorizationCode from the provider but then how did you use oauth2, extending torii authenticate method? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using both packages is the way to go. The Ember Simple Auth packages are built so that you always include the base package (ember-simple-auth) plus any additional packages for authentication strategies etc. that you want to use. If you e.g. want to use the OAuth 2.0 package to authenticate against your own server plus the torii package to authenticate against Facebook, Google+ etc. then you simply include both packages. There will also be no duplicate code that you're requiring as the common functionality is in the ember-simple-auth package and the ember-simple-auth-oauth2 as well as the ember-simple-auth-torii packages only include the code that's specific to the respective authentication strategy.